# Disable highlight on q-item (Quasar Framework)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, quasar-framework

When the current url is equal to **:to="something"** property, the q-item is highlighted in blue.

[image]

But I want q-item to keep black without highlighted in blue even though the current url is equal to the **:to="something"** property.

[image]

This is my q-item code (I use Quasar v2.0.4):

```js
<q-item
  :to="{ name: 'home' }"
>
  <q-item-section avatar>
    <q-icon name="home" size="md" />
  </q-item-section>
  <q-item-section> 
    Home
  </q-item-section>
</q-item>
```

Is it possible to disable highlight on q-item?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **active-class="remove-active"**:

```js
<q-item
  active-class="remove-active" // Here
  :to="{ name: 'home' }"
>
  <q-item-section avatar>
    <q-icon name="home" size="md" />
  </q-item-section>
  <q-item-section> 
    Home
  </q-item-section>
</q-item>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use **active-class="q-item-no-link-highlighting"** to make q-item inactive keeping black:

```js
<q-item
  active-class="q-item-no-link-highlighting" // Here
  :to="{ name: 'home' }"
>
  <q-item-section avatar>
    <q-icon name="home" size="md" />
  </q-item-section>
  <q-item-section> 
    Home
  </q-item-section>
</q-item>
```